# Dart questions on StringBuffer

Tags: dart

After reading the source code of [hart](https://github.com/lvivski/hart), there's this thing I don't understand. He's using `StringBuffer` to create a class, here's taken from the source :

```
var buff = new StringBuffer('''

class View {
  Map _views;

  render(String name, Map params) {
    return _views[name](params).get();
  }

  register(String name, handler(Map params)) {
    if (_views == null) {
      _views = {};
    }
    _views[name] = handler;
  }

  View() {
''');
```

Can we make a class using `StringBuffer` because I thought `StringBuffer` only used as a string manipulator ?

Answer (score 2):

From the hart package's readme:

> Dart doesn't allow any code evaluation so you have to precompile all
>   your templates.

So looks like hart generates dart source, which can then be fed into the dart compiler.